# Returning Store Categories with eBay API using PHP

Tags: php, ebay-api

Which API call should I use to return all categories from User Store?

I'm trying to do it with PHP.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=$myappid&siteid=77&CategoryID=-1&version=729&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories');
```

But it's returning only the eBay categories, not the User Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shopping API cannot retrieve a users store categories. You will need to use the Trading API.

You would have to use the GetStore call. Which would return a `StoreType` object containing a `StoreCustomCategoryArrayType` object.

**EDIT:**

1. First you sign up to the [eBay Developer Program.](https://developer.ebay.com/join/)
2. Then get a set of keys [from here.](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/account/default.aspx)
3. You will need to set some headers on your request but you can read about them at [Making a Call.](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Concepts/MakingACall.html)
4. Make the call replacing the variables with your own.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <GetStoreRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
     <RequesterCredentials>
         <eBayAuthToken>$token</eBayAuthToken>
     </RequesterCredentials>
     <UserID>$userID</UserID>
     <Version>$version</Version>
   </GetStoreRequest>
   ```

Comment: I get it now, can you write me a valid call with GetStore call type? In Ebay Api development page I can not find any example for it

Comment: You have to use a different endpoint as well: https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll